Foucault pendulum with General Relativity
It is well-known that the plane of the swing of a Foucault pendulum exhibits parallel transport (wrt to the Levi-Civita connection) of a round sphere.
Seeing as Einstein's relativity theories geometrize inertial motion as autoparallel transport in pseudo-Riemannian geometry, it seems a bit suspicious that the above should just be a coincidence.
In the following, I propose an explanation via GR. Any thoughts are welcome to improve the argument.
Namely, assuming that the frequency of the Foucault pendulum is very small (compared to the time of one revolution of the Earth), treat the pendulum as being attached to the reference frame
$$(x \circ \gamma)^i (\tau) = (ct(\tau) , R_{Earth}(\tau), \theta(\tau) = \theta_0 , \omega \tau)$$
where $\omega$ is $360^0 / 24$ hours and $\theta_0$ is the colatitude of the pendulum in the Schwarzschild geometry (let us assume the Kerr corrections are negligible); i.e. the pendulums base point rotates around with the Earth as usual.
One can check as expected the proper acceleration of this curve is always totally in the $\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \big|_{\gamma(\tau)}$ direction: i.e. as expected by the equivalance principle, standing on a slowly rotating, massive sphere is at each proper time locally the same as acceleration in flat spacetime.
So that means during one (short) swing, one should from the accelerated reference frame see a pendulum that behaves exactly as the basic examples in a undergrad mechanics text. Now importantly, the net acceleration of the pendulum bob during one swing is entirely normal to the surface of the spacelike hypersurface representing the Earth's regular surface.
Thus one may get a "densishley defined" vector field along $\gamma$ which is the spacetime tangent (4-velocity) to the bob each time it visits the bottom of its swing (so a vector in $T_{\gamma(\tau_i)} S^2 \subset T_{\gamma(\tau_i)} M$ for various evenly spaced $t_i$). Furthermore, in each time chunk between visits to the bottom of the swing, the covariant derivative (force acting on the bob) is totally normal to the $S^2$, so one gets that the tangent to the bob is the unique parallel vector field along $\gamma$ with the right initial conditions.

I actually expect that ultimately it won't work.
You write:

[...] the net acceleration of the pendulum bob during one swing is entirely normal to the surface of the spacelike hypersurface representing the Earth's regular surface.



The image below represents a cross section of the Earth.

In the image the oblateness (of the Earth) is exaggerated. In the case of the actual Earth the oblateness is small, but it is an essential feature.
The equatorial radius of the Earth is about 20 kilometers more than the polar radius.
In the image the blue arrow represents newtonian gravity, and the red arrow represent the normal force exerted upon a suspended object, such as a pendulum bob.
The blue arrow and the red arrow are not              180 degrees opposite. They are not quite aligned, and that angle gives rise to a centripetal force, represented with the green arrow.
The equatorial bulge of the solid Earth is the reason that the water of the Earth does not all accumulate at the Equator. At every latituded the equatorial bulge provides the required centripetal force that makes fluids (water, air) remain at the same latitude.
At 45 degrees latitude the angle between newtonian gravity and the normal force is about 0.1 degree.
The net acceleration is a centripetal acceleration.




Incidentally, there is a very interesting article by the historian of science Dennis Lehmkuhl on the following subject: Einstein's opinion on whether GR represents a geometrization of theory of gravity/motion.
Dennis Lehmkuhl shows the following: around 1925 and 1926 Einstein exchanged letters with people who pointed out to Einstein the idea of interpreting GR as a geometrization of the gravitational interaction.
In reply Einstein objected to such an interpretation.
Two examples of how he phrased his objections:

I cannot, namely, concede that the assertion that the theory of relativity traces physics back to geometry has a clear meaning.


Ich kann nämlich nicht zugeben, dass
die Behauptung, die Relativitätstheorie führe die Physik auf Geometrie zurück einen klaren Sinn habe.



Using a similar reasoning Maxwell and Hertz could have denoted the electromagnetic equations of the vacuum as “geometrical” because the geometrical concept of a vector occurs in these equations.


Mit ähnlicher Argumentation hätten Maxwell und Hertz die elektromagnetischen Gleichungen
des Vakuums als “geometrische” bezeichnen können, weil der geometrische Begriff
des Vektors dabei in diesen Gleichungen auftritt.’



So:
Einstein was quite dismissive of the notion of regarding GR as a geometrization.
I'm not suggesting that the notion of geometrization should be abandoned, but I do think the arguments against the geometrization interpretation are compelling.

From the article you linked: "What does it mean to say that GR ‘geometrized’ gravity? Does it just mean
that gravity is described by using particular mathematical tools? Or does it
mean that gravity has been ontologically reduced to (spacetime) geometry
in some sense? In this section, we shall see that Einstein believed that
at best ‘geometrization’ means the former — and is thus trivial — and at
worst it means the latter and is wrong."

In my post, the use of 'geometrization' is with the first definition. Nevertheless, thank you for the interesting article.
